# exclude some fields from @Valid validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, annotations

I use Spring's `@Valid` annotation for validate bean's fields which annotated with `javax.constraints` annotations.

But I faced a problem when I need to exclude some fields from validation (only for some cases).

I did an investigation didn't found any usefull ways and most of answers were dated as 2010-2011. It is quite surprisingly since this situatuion is so common.

Is there any changes from that times for Spring 4.+? Or maybe anyone can share personal experience how to beat this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use validation group, and  [`@Validated`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation.

There's a detail explanation in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html

The approach is based on [hibernate validator's groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) and it enables you to group the validation based on the marker interface and apply it on handler level, example as given in the link

```
@RequestMapping(value = "stepTwo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String stepTwo(@Validated(Account.ValidationStepTwo.class) Account account, Errors errors) {
  if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      return VIEW_STEP_TWO;
  }
  return "redirect:summary";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. 
Note for everyone: name of `@Validated` can be misguiding because as I thought at a first glance I should pass to it groups to be skipped but in reality is reverse.
Also, as a placeholder for validate only default group you can use for better readability: `@Validated(javax.validation.groups.Default.class)` which equals to `@Validated` without parameters.

Comment: [There is also answer](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/117289-validated-s-given-groups-should-consider-default-group-or-not) how not to duplicate `Default.class` for every fields. But unfortunately it suits only for adding field to default validation, not exclude it.