# javax.validation.Validator exclude some fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have two different services: the first one is to save an object to the database and the second one is for updating the existing object.

I am using validation constraints for my object such as (@NotBlank, @Size, @Pattern, etc.) and in first case, I need to validate all fields of the object but in the latter case, some fields need to be excluded from Validator.

Currently, I am using javax.validation.Validator for validation. Here is my object...

```
public class Person {

  private Long id;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(max = 45)
  private String name;

  @Size(max = 5000)
  private String description;

  @Size(max = 300)
  private String address;
}
```

... and I would like to exclude the "address" field during the update validation.

```
@Named
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class PersonService {

private final PersonRepository repository;
private final Validator validator = buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

public Person save(Person person) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);

    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
      throw new ConstraintViolationException(new HashSet<>(violations));
    }

    return repository.save(person);
}

public Person update(Person person) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person); //exclude address field here

    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
      throw new ConstraintViolationException(new HashSet<>(violations));
    }

    return repository.save(person);
}
}
```

Comment: I also checked this solution here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798346/exclude-some-fields-from-valid-validation but I think, it might be outdated and there could be better solutions.

Comment: Use validation Group https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups

Answer (score -1):

If you need to exclude address property, just set it null before validation. And set it to its previous value after validation:

```
public Person update(Person person) {
    String address = person.getAddress();
    person.setAddress(null);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<JobAd>> violations = validator.validate(person);

    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
      throw new ConstraintViolationException(new HashSet<>(violations));
    }

    person.setAddress(address)
    return repository.save(person);
}
```